# Looping through enums as parameters

Tags: java, loops, enums, iteration

So I'm coding Blackjack in Java and I've stored my suit and rank values in enums

```
public enum Suit
{
   spades, hearts, clubs, diamonds
}



public enum Rank
{
    two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king, ace
}
```

I have a Deck class which keeps a Stack of 'Cards'. 
Cards contain fields for Suit and Rank.

```
public class Card
{
    static Suit suit;
    static Rank rank;


    Card(Suit suit, Rank rank)  
    {

    this.suit = suit;
    this.rank = rank;

    }


    public String toString()
    {
    return rank + " of " + suit;
    }

    //getters and setters ommitted
}
```

The constructor in Deck should be iterating through each each suit and rank and passing these on as parameters to create a deck of 52 cards, but it seems to be stuck on the last values of each and I end up with 52 'aces of clubs'. I don't understand why, as the suit and rank seem to print correctly, it just seems to be when they're passed as a parameter to add() that they misbehave.

```
public class Deck
{
    static Stack<Card> d = new Stack<Card>();

    Deck()
    {
    if (!d.isEmpty())
    {
        clear(); //Empties the stack if constructor is called again
    }

    for (Suit suit : Suit.values())
    {
        for (Rank rank : Rank.values())
        {
        //System.out.println(suit + " " + rank);
        //This seems to print the right values

        add(new Card(suit, rank)); //These are stuck on 'clubs' and 'ace'
        }
    }

    System.out.println(d);

    shuffle(); //Method which shuffles the deck

    }

    public static void add(Card c)
    {
    d.addElement(c);
    }

    //shuffle(), clear() and other methods omitted
}
```

The full project can be seen on [github](https://github.com/khal28/jblackjack), if that helps.

Comment: make sure you understand what a static variable is. You seem to misunderstand them(it is the cause of your problems).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suit and rank fields in Card should not be static!

Neither should your Deck fields!

Static fields are per-class, so your Card constructor is *overwriting* the same value every time it's called.

Answer (score 0):

This is abnormal. You can just extend `Deck` from `Stack`.

```
public class Deck
{
    static Stack<Card> d = new Stack<Card>();
```

In that case you can call `add`, `clear`, `shuffle` from Collection directly on the `Deck`.

```
public class Deck extends Stack<Card> {
    //add, clear are already there from Stack
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the values() method on your enum.

```
for ((Rank rank : Rank.values()) {
  // do what you want
}
```

This values() method ***is implicitly declared by the compiler***. So it is not listed on Enum doc.